# Determining the primary key from a SQL Server statement

Tags: sql-server

Given the following T-SQL statement how do I (by inspection) determine the primary key? If it isn't listed (like I suspect) what would it look like?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BLDGINFO](
    [LBLDGRUNNO] [int] NULL,
    [LBLDGNO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FBIVOLUME] [float] NULL,
    [FBIACOND] [float] NULL,
    [NBIHTYPE] [float] NULL,
    [NBILTYPE] [float] NULL,
    [NBISTORIES] [float] NULL,
    [NBIFTYPE] [float] NULL,
    [NBIBEDS] [float] NULL,
    [NBIUNITS] [float] NULL,
    [SBIRATENO] [nvarchar](31) NULL,
    [NBICTYPE] [float] NULL,
    [NBIYEARBLT] [int] NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [NBITHBNDRY] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: As BluesRockAddict points out below... this example does not have a Primary Key defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a primary key has been defined at all, it will be `LBLDGNO`. However, it is quite possible that there is no primary key defined at all. You can determine this as follows:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM sys.indexes i, sys.index_columns ic, sys.objects o, sys.columns c
WHERE o.object_id = i.object_id
AND ic.index_id = i.index_id AND ic.object_id = i.object_id
AND c.object_id = o.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
AND i.is_primary_key = 1
AND o.name = 'BLDGINFO'
```

This query will return all columns included in the primary key. If it returns an empty resultset, then there is no primary key defined.

Answer (score 2):

The only field in your table that possibly could work as a primary key is `LBLDGNO` because a primary key column can not be nullable.

Comment: Ahh I didn't catch this! However doesn't it need to be UNIQUE? So as I'm working through this I see that fields which begin with "L" appear to be fake Foreign Keys. As an aside in MSSQL can you use a Foreign Key as a Primary?

Comment: You can't use a foreign key as a primary key, since they are different constraints. However, it is possible for a field to belong to both the primary key and a foreign key, as would be the case when creating a 1-1 relationship. The primary key does need to be unique, but this constraint is applied by the foreign key, and not by the table definition itself.

Answer (score 1):

The table definition in your question does not contain primary key, here is an example with primary key defined as id column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BLDGINFO](
    id int NOT NULL,
    [LBLDGRUNNO] [int] NULL,
    [LBLDGNO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FBIVOLUME] [float] NULL,
    [FBIACOND] [float] NULL,
    [NBIHTYPE] [float] NULL,
    [NBILTYPE] [float] NULL,
    [NBISTORIES] [float] NULL,
    [NBIFTYPE] [float] NULL,
    [NBIBEDS] [float] NULL,
    [NBIUNITS] [float] NULL,
    [SBIRATENO] [nvarchar](31) NULL,
    [NBICTYPE] [float] NULL,
    [NBIYEARBLT] [int] NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [NBITHBNDRY] [int] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: So it _can_ look very similar to straight SQL.  Interesting as I haven't seen this yet.